# Exhibit this correspondence.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

We know that there is a one-to-one correspondence between the $r$ with $0\le r\lt20$ with $gcd(r,20)=1$ and the pairs $(r_1,r_2)$ where $0\le r_1\lt4$, where $0\le r_2\lt5$ such that $gcd(r_1,4)=1$ and such that $gcd(r_2,5)=1$.  Exhibit this correspondence.

Comment: A lot like your other question.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should read about the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).  You may also find it helpful to take some specific pairs (r,s) (of integers modulo 4 and 5, respectively) and "assemble" them to form a residue class modulo 20.